# In/to/on the company's account

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'm confused about the preposition. Which one is better to use when we talk about social media accounts? For example, "Repost the ad **in/to/on** the company's account"

Comment: While the linked thread asks about the same prepositions, I think the context is different enough that this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context I personally would favor the use of "to".  But "on" and "to" are also used, and any of the three would be correcty understood. To the best of my knowledge, there is no rule of grammar involved here. All three choices give grammatically valid sentences. That makes it a matter of usage and style, and I am not aware of any overwhelming difference in the frequency of usage here.

When one is spoeaking of a financial account, one bills items **to** an acount, but places charges **on** an account. But the customary usage for a social media account is not as well established.

Comment: Thank you very much)))